# difference in get a submat in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I have tested the following two snippets and they give a different result. The second one is right. I do not understand why it is and I wonder if there is a bug in opencv?

A result matrix f_sub is different in those examples.

1)

```
Mat f = Mat::zeros(96,112,CV_8UC1);
randu(f,0,255);

Mat f_sub = f(cv::Rect(17,14,78,68));


//mat2File("f.mm",f,1);
//mat2File("f_sub.mm",f_sub,1);
exit(0);
```

2)

```
Mat f = Mat::zeros(96,112,CV_8UC1);
randu(f,0,255);

Mat f_sub = f(cv::Rect(17,14,78,68)).clone();


//mat2File("f.mm",f,1);
//mat2File("f_sub.mm",f_sub,1);
exit(0);
```

The mat2File is just print a  mat into  a file

```
void mat2File(string filename, Mat M, int y)
{
    ofstream fout(filename.c_str());
    //fout << M.rows<<" "<<M.cols<<endl;
    uchar *M_ptr = (uchar*)M.ptr();
    for(size_t i=0; i<M.rows; i++)
    {
        fout<<endl;
        for(size_t j=0; j<M.cols; j++)
        {
            fout<< (size_t)M_ptr[i*M.cols+j]<<" ";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you're using different randomness `randu()` (expecting different results for running it two times)? Also, showing the content of `mat2File` is useful.

Comment: If you're changing something inside f in the first snippet  you'll change also f_sub. In the second snippet instead you won't.

Comment: Actually, I met this problem in the implement of a project. The project is complex and the above code is just an example for showing the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mat2File` seems to be a culprit.

`M_ptr[i*M.cols+j]` is incorrect for non-continuous matrices because pitch between matrix lines is greater than `M.cols`. You'd better use `M.at<uchar>(y,x)` to access Mat pixels.